# Issue with login credentials for Android TV app review on Google Play Console

Tags: android, authentication, google-play-console, android-tv

I'm encountering an issue with the login credentials for my Android TV app during the review process on Google Play Console. I receive an error indicating that the provided credentials are not valid for accessing the in-app content.

I've ensured that the login credentials meet the requirements specified by Google Play Console, and it is accessible. I've verified the login credentials and tested them in the TV app to ensure they grant access to the in-app content successfully. However, the issue persists during the review process.

I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue and ensure that the login credentials provided are accepted for the TV app review on Google Play Console.